# GraphSharp .Net Graph Layout Engine

Tags: .net, graph, graph-theory, directed-graph

I want to use the apparently fantastic GraphSharp library but the project has NO documentation.

Specifically I'm interested in using the layout engine and not interested in the WPF control. 
I simply want to calculate a layout (positions of the nodes) for a given graph and layout algorithm.

Does anyone have any advice, tips, links on how to use GraphSharp.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some useful discussions from the GraphSharp website:

[How do I get X and Y coordinates of a Vertex Control?](http://graphsharp.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=79745) (`Vertex` is a.k.a. `Node`.)

[Error when overriding Template for Edge Control](http://graphsharp.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=71641) (example of an `Edge` template).

[Custom Vertices?](http://graphsharp.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=68634)

[Vertex ItemTemplate](http://graphsharp.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=60919)

They've been the most use to me, but I'm still trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Graph# is not well documented but you can find something here:

1. http://graphsharp.codeplex.com
   Graph# discussion page covers some common topics. Graph# tutorial page has several videos that may help you to start. Also there is an article about creating a custom graph.
2. There is some description of the project's design here: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/graphsharp/index.php?title=Main_Page.

Everything else, unfortunately, you have to figure out yourself by digging into the source code.